# Creating a repeating vlookup table for raw materials

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I want to achieve the following.

User selects the item they want in A1 (dropdown menu), called ITEM1

In the second sheet, there are tables with the following properties such as

```
ITEMS   MATERIALS   AMOUNT  
ITEM1   material1   3  
ITEM1   material2   5  
ITEM2   material3   1  
ITEM3   material4   12
```

This means that in order to issue an order with ITEM1, the user needs 3xmaterial1 and 5xmaterial2.

However, down the list, some materials need further raw materials to create. For instance

```
ITEMS             MATERIALS           AMOUNT  
material1         submaterial1-1      4  
submaterial1-1    submaterial1-1-1    2
```

But not all materials have submaterials.

I want to display the total raw materials only.

So when user selects **ITEM1** they should get on the same sheet the total amount of raw materials they need:

submaterial1-1-1 **x 24**

Material2 **x 5**

I can write a simple VLOOKUP if the item does not have any sub-materials, but i just cannot make it go all the way to the very final raw material, which is the only information my users need to see.

Note: The writing of the tables is not set in stone. I can, if needed, adjust them in any fashion.

---

Edit: Clarification below as requested.
User wants to order "Orange Juice with Bacardi".
The raw materials for "Orange Juice with Bacardi" is 2 x Oranges, and 1x Bacardi. Assume that we are producing Bacardi as well. In this case, we would hypothetically need 3 units of Alcohol and 2 units of Sugar.

So the raw material breakdown of an "Orange Juice with Bacardi" is:
2x Oranges
3x alcohol
2x sugar

I want the VLOOKUP table to give me just that. 
I'm using 2 VLOOKUPs, one for the material and one for the amount of items.

`=VLOOKUP($A$1,Materials!$B$2:$D$4, 2, FALSE)` 
and
`=VLOOKUP($A$1,Materials!$B$2:$D$4, 3, FALSE)`

But I cannot go "one level down further". Currently I would only get

```
Oranges 2
Bacardi 1
```

but I want

```
Oranges 2
Alcohol 3
Sugar 2
```

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve I'm unable to understand so that editing is also not looking possible. My  suggestions are, 1. Edit the post and try to clear your real need. 2. Better include the formula you have tried for the issue, help us to realize your need.

Comment: Edited the OP for more clarification. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the chance to change the tool from Excel to something else. This is a task could be managed much better with a database tool (Access, SQLite, MySQL...)

Comment: I was afraid of this.. Unfortunately I don't have any database tools, nor any experience with any of them.

Comment: Have you tried nesting this in an IF() statement? You say you have a VLOOKUP() that works for the top level, if you add this to an IF() statement you might be able to solve your problem... IF(submaterial1-1-1,VLOOKUP(),(IF(submaterial1-1(VLOOKUP(),VLOOKUP()))).

Comment: @Kevin's approach is the way to go.  The formula will get quite long depending on how many levels of sub-materials there are.  It sounds like there can be 3 levels: materials, sub-materials, and sub-sub-materials. Is that correct?

Comment: I have 3 columns, but the sub-materials go as deep as 14 to 15 levels. Unfortunately I could not get a working IF + VLOOKUP due to the following reason:

All my data is laid out in 3 columns. This is because some materials are repeating in both columns, and since there are 14 to 15 levels.

For instance, 

`Mat1 Mat2 Amount

Laminated Beam Oak 3

Composite Beam Laminated Beam 2

Strong Beam Laminated Beam 5

Strong Composite Beam Strong Beam 5`


I just want the result to give me "375 Oak" when user selects Ironhide Beam.

Comment: Can you post 2 lines of sample data and add an expected result to both lines?

Answer (score 0):

As the requirement is to display the raw materials on lowest level, one way to do it using only VLOOKUP would be to create a table that will have a line for each raw material, fixed columns for ITEM, RAW_MATERIAL and it's pieces. the parent materials of the raw one would be in same row. This kind of table would be harder to maintain but the goal will be achieved.

Adding 3 examples of such table:

[image: 3 variations]